# Emulate LEFT JOIN with mapreduce?

Tags: mapreduce, left-join

Emulating an INNER JOIN with mapreduce is relatively trivial, mapping common keys and joining values in the reducer the job gets done. But when it comes to a LEFT OUTER JOIN one faces the problem of combinations filling empties for the Right table when there are keys in the Left table not present in the Right table. The non matching keys would be discarded when mapped into the reducer, how can one then add these non matching keys from the Left table?

For example, let's assume we have two files:

```
Left = {'matches': 1}
Right = {'matches': 2,
         'matches_not': 3}
```

One would want an output like:

```
Output: {'matches-matches': [1, 2],
         'matches-matches_not': [1, None]}
```

Emitting the common key 'matches' from the mapper has no problem as both occurences from Left and Right will get to the reducer with common key, but how can one get the combination for the 'matches_not' if it never makes it to the reducer?

Comment: I made a typing mistake and switched the Left and Right names in the example, and I just edited. I see why you could not find a problem with the name switching. Thanks, now I see the case is the reducer will get the "matches_not" not grouping it with "matches" so the way to determine the left outer elements would be telling if the number of occurences making it to the reducer is less than 2, would you agree?

Comment: Excellent, I'm going to try this now, thanks!

Comment: Moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reducer will get all records mapped, even if the matching record is absent. You just have to be add an indicator to each key/value pair showing which side it came from.  That indicator will help your reduce() method determine the exact case you're dealing with for each key.

For more details on how to set that up, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767045/join-with-hadoop-in-java) to a different question about join.

Comment: Thanks, this does it, I have to add, the indicator should be part of the value, not the key, unless you can suggest a way to do it grouping with different keys?